# Input text with mask to Date Mysql

Tags: php

i'm trying to input a date in a `input type='text'` in a mask `d/m/Y`

When I post my form I use the following syntax:
`$Nascimento = date_format($_POST['nascimento'],"Y-m-d");`

My SQL column is formatted as:
`Date`

When I submit it gives me the following error:
`date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, string given in /myfile.php on line 191`

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You have to convert the following code to Date-time since tour DB has Date-time field for it.

strtotime - Parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp

The function expects to be given a string containing an English date format and will try to parse that format into a Unix timestamp (the number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC), relative to the timestamp given in now, or the current time if now is not supplied.

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['nascimento']))
```

Comment: Almost there. The value in my SQL output was `1969-12-31`. In my text input was `21/09/2016`

Answer (score 0):

[`date_format()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.format.php) doesn't return a date, it returns a string.

You can run [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtotime.php) to make it become a proper date.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with:

`date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace("/","-",$_POST['nascimento'])));`